# For List: NoneType object has no attribute append

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, nonetype

When I try to append strings to an list-value in my dictionary, I keep getting this error, so when I tried to check the type of my object (see second line in code from the bottom) it came back with "unhashable type: list".

I am attempting to take info from a CSV and put it in a dictionary. The CSV has a list of name with comments associated with those names. Many of the names reoccur with multiple comments so I am trying to store all of these comments in a list which will be the value while the authors name will be the key.
Ex:

```
dictionary = {'Mike': 'Hey there', 'Grandma': 'Good morning', 'Mike': 'Yes it is'}
```

would actually be:

```
dictionary = {'Mike': ['Hey there', 'Yes it is'], 'Grandma': ['Good morning']}
```

as this way, when I am receiving the data, I can simply add in another comment if need. Such as if I get a new comment for Mike that's 'Goodbye' I can simply append this to his list of values.

My code is as follows:

```
def extract_data():
    data_dict = {}

    with open(data_CSV_file,'rt') as file:
        #to avoid complications with the null byte
        data = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in file)
        count = 0

        # keep list of authors to check when we're adding
        list_of_authors = []

        # get data from CSV
        for row in data:

            if count < 400:
                # check if we've already added this person
                if row[AUTHOR] not in list_of_authors:
                    list_of_comments = [row[COMMENT]]

                    data_dict.update({row[AUTHOR]: list_of_comments})
                    list_of_authors.append(row[AUTHOR])
                    count += 1



                # if so, simply add to their list of comments
                else:
                    cvalue = data_dict.get(row[AUTHOR])
                    #print(type(data_dict.get(cvalue)))
                    data_dict[row[0]] = cvalue.append(row[1])
    return data_dict
```

Since I'm reading in the data from a CSV file, I figured this would be the best way as the CSV file isn't organized so I don't know where the authors next comment will come up and don't want to have to search through the entire CSV file to get all of their comments every time I come across a new name.

Comment: You should add the full traceback, and attempt to provide a [mcve]. There are a bunch of undefined variables. Ideally, we should be able to copy and paste the code and reporduce the error, so even a small example data set would be very helpful

Comment: Just a hunch: `cvalue = data_dict.get(row[AUTHOR])` -> `cvalue = data_dict.get(row[AUTHOR], [])`. Although the likely failing line `data_dict[row[0]] = cvalue.append(row[1])` doesn't really make any sense because `.append` always returns `None`.

Comment: So, the problem is that you are replacing the list in your dict with `None`, since `cvalue.append(row[1])` will return `None`. You really only need `data_dict[row[AUTHUR]].append(row[COMMENT])` in your else-block. That's it. Also, in your `if` block, you use `.update`, here: `data_dict.update({row[AUTHOR]: list_of_comments})` that's really not what `.update` is for, for a single item, just use`data_dict[row[AUTHOR]] = list_of_comments`, use update to update a dict with another dict (or mapping) of unknown size.

Comment: as an aside, if you are encountering issues with null bytes in your string, perhaps you actually have a utf-16 encoded file? try `open(<name>, encoding='utf16')`